# How to configure AutoMapper using JsonProperty attribute

Tags: c#, json, json.net, automapper

How would I need to configure AutoMapper to be able to convert a DataTable containing columns "C" and "D" to a list of MyClass by using the [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute for mapping?

```
public class MyClass
{
     [JsonProperty("C")]
     public string A { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("D")]
     public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using metadata from Json.NET's own [contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) you can configure a name mapping from an [`IDataRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatarecord) to properties of your type `MyClass`.  Having done that, you can map from any `IDataReader` including the one returned by [`DataTable.CreateDataReader()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.createdatareader) to a list of instances of your type.

First add the following extension method:

```
public static class AutomapperJsonExtensions
{
    static readonly IContractResolver defaultResolver = new JsonSerializer().ContractResolver;

    public static void CreateJsonDataReaderMap<TDestination>(this IMapperConfigurationExpression cfg, IContractResolver resolver = null)
    {
        resolver = resolver ?? defaultResolver;
        var contract = resolver.ResolveContract(typeof(TDestination)) as JsonObjectContract ?? throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("{0} is not a JSON object.", typeof(TDestination)));

        var map = cfg.CreateMap<IDataRecord, TDestination>();

        foreach (var p in contract.Properties.Where(p => !p.Ignored && p.Writable))
        {
            // Map PropertyName in reader to UnderlyingName in TDestination
            map.ForMember(p.UnderlyingName, opt => opt.MapFrom(r => r[p.PropertyName]));
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can configure a [`MapperConfiguration`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#how-do-i-use-automapper) and map your table to a `List<MyClass>` as follows:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateJsonDataReaderMap<MyClass>();
});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
using var reader = table.CreateDataReader();
var result = mapper.Map<List<MyClass>>(reader);
```

Notes:

- Error handling for properties present in the table but not in the class, or vice versa, has not been implemented, but presumably could be.
- If your table was created using camel-cased column names you can pass an instance of [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm) as the second argument to `CreateJsonDataReaderMap()` and names should map correctly.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TwaSGS) which uses AutoMapper version 9.